# Pymongo, query on list field, and/or

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection with some documents like:

```
{
    _id: 5,
    vals: [100, 1100, 1500]
},
{
    _id: 10,
    vals: [1100, 1700]
}
```

How can I query for documents that have, in `vals` field:

- 1100
- 1700 OR 100
- 100 AND 1100

I can use some comprehension magic like:

```
g = lambda codes: (
    d for d in collection.find() if any(code in d["vals"] for code in codes)
)
g([100, 1700]).next()
```

Or, for the AND:

```
g = lambda codes: (
    d for d in collection.find() if all(code in d["vals"] for code in codes)
)
g([100, 1100]).next()
```

This seems a little clunky though if there is some find magic that can be done with the driver.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
yourmongocoll.find({"vals":1100})
yourmongocoll.find({"$or":[ {"vals":1700}, {"vals":100}]})
yourmongocoll.find({"$and":[ {"vals":100}, {"vals":1100}]})
```

i would recommend reading [Mongodb Advanced queries](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-$in)

you will also find [$in](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in) ...useful

Comment: doesn't scale to 10s of `vals` very well though.

Comment: @SkylarSaveland It does scale to 10s or even 1,000s if you use list comprehension. For example, if you have a list of values; values = [100,1100,1700], then your code looks like this yourmongocoll.find({"$and": [{"vals": val} for val in values] })